# Is metzitzah b'peh required when an adult is circumcised or in the case of hatafas dam bris?

Tags: halacha, brit-milah, health-safety-shmira, current-events, age

As we've discussed in a general [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/is-metzitzah-bpeh-a-must/18783#18783) regarding the requirements for metzitzah b'peh (MBP), the direct-oral-contact technique to draw blood from the penis of an 8-day old infant at his bris milah has become controversial as a serious health issue.  My question is whether the sources who advocate metzitzah b'peh with direct oral contact for infants also require it when an adult Jewish male is seeking circumcision (as many Russian immigrants needed to), or in the case of adult male converts. Also, if the man was already circumcised and requires only hatafas dam bris (a ceremonial drawing of some blood), would metzitzah b'peh with direct oral contact be necessary?

I ask these questions because when I converted I did not have MBP, and I have not heard of any other converts having gone through that.  However, I and most converts I know only had a hatafas dam bris.  Moreover, in either case blood could be drawn out of an adult penis more easily, it would seem to me, through squeezing the tissue, whereas an infant's penis may simply be too small to do that without causing injury.  That's just my speculation, however.

Comment: @msh210: Thanks for your edit.  What would you call MBP where a tube is used?  Doesn't "peh" imply "by mouth" already?

Comment: BruceJames, I *think* the term is used for anything by mouth, even without skin-to-skin contact, as opposed to other squeezing methods.

Comment: @BruceJames Even with a tube, it's still the peh (mouth) that's doing the metzitza (sucking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding adult Brit for conversion where the man is not previously cirucumcised at least according to some people they do.  Rav Mordechai Eliyahu writes such in his sefer on Milah Ozer Eliyahu 264:4.  Rav Shlomo Shochet also writes that it is necessary in his sefer Milah Shleimah, 4:29(also see the Teshuvot he brings in chapter 12 and 13).  His text is the required course work for certification by the Rabbinate.

Regarding Hatafat Dam Brit, no there is not need for MBP.  As it is not considered a true Brit Milah.  See above locations.

Comment: awwww, how does this work exactly?