# What things are done differently for an adult circumcision?

Tags: medicine, brit-milah, baby-infant

I have never attended an adult circumcision, and I don't know anyone, personally, who was circumcised as an adult. I'm curious if there are any notable differences between an adult and child circumcision. Examples:

- I've never seen local anesthetics used for a child. Perhaps, babies are more tolerant of the pain than adults. Do they use any anesthetic for adults?
- I assume that there is no *sandak* at an adult brit? The sandak usually holds the baby on his lap. I don't think a sandak could hold an adult on his lap.
- In what position is the adult? Lying on a "mat"? Sitting?
- Is recovery time longer for an adult than for a child? Are there any physical dangers / problems that may occur afterwards for an adult that are different than those that may occur for a baby? (E.g. different or higher degree of infections, etc.)
- In the prayer after the child's brit, there's a phrase that says (loose translation):

> This little one shall grow. In the manner that he entered the brit, so
>   shall he enter Torah, Chuppah and good deeds.

I assume the we eliminate the 1st sentence. And, if he's married we would eliminate the mentioning of "Chuppah". Correct? Any substitutions, other changes?

Please include any other differences that I have not mentioned, above.

Comment: The relevant body area is covered for the blessing IINM for an adult

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27853/is-metzitzah-bpeh-required-when-an-adult-is-circumcised-or-in-the-case-of-hataf

Comment: "I've never seen local anesthetics used for a child" https://youtu.be/Uvkz6UEmi4Y?t=372

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_milah

Answer (score 7):

1. THe Gemmorah (Kiddushin 29 I think) says: "If father didn't Ccized him he's obligated to Ccze himself when he grows up" (it is not clear who's Mitzvah it is in the first place - חפצא or גברא).
2. It's done in a medical facility under supervision, local anesthetics, you lay down on a table as any surgery.
3. The Mohel asks you if you appoint him as your Shaliah, and since you're already on the table, you have no choice. He says the Brocho and starts the surgery.
4. After it's done and you can stand (as long as the narcosis lasts) he/you/ Rabbi pours a glass of wine and ways the Brocho. I don't remember what exactly the wording was, but it is not Meakev for Brochos, as we hold (also can be said in any language). One is usually given his Hebrew name, just like little ones.
5. The additions (קטן זה גדול יהיה etc) can be said in any situation and interpreted spiritually, it is not Meakev either.
6. Recovery depends on your age (as any physical recovery) and your sexual activity (mostly your erections). As it is only "skin deep" it is not too long. (That's a question for a different group).
7. You can throw a "Thank you" party (סעודת מצווה) inviting 10 and more male adults, eating bread, bentching and saying Divrey Torah anytime later.

<sub>This is my personal experience</sub>

Comment: Sources, please?

Comment: @DonielF I assumed it was personal experience. Am I wrong, Al Berko?

Comment: @ezra If that is what it’s from, if he edits that in it would make for a much better answer.

Comment: @DonielF I did it at 18 when starting my Teshuva process.

Comment: There is one other part of the brit that is meakev - I'd rather not state it clearly for obvious reasons. How is that done? (If you don't mind answering)

Comment: @theblitz Do you mean Priah? The two components of circumcision that are Meakev are Milah and Priah. (Medical treatment of the wound is obligatory, of course, for other reasons, but it isn't Meakev the Mitzva. The Gemara says that a Mohel who doesn't treat the wound properly (with appropriate poultices and cleaning) should be removed from his job as Mohel.)

Comment: Actually I was talking about "metzitza" :O

Comment: @theblitz you mean cleaning the wound? I assume they use alcohol swabs nowadays and sterile bandages. But anyway, cleaning the wound isn't meakev at all. It's just a really, really good idea. A Mohel who doesn't clean the wound should certainly be fired (as the Gemara says), and all the more so one who purposefully makes it dirtier, endangering the life of the patient.

Comment: Re. #3: When lying on the [operating] table and the *mohel* asks the *nimol* if he appoints him as *shaliach* “you have no choice” but to assent. In your case, for example, did you want to do the operation/circumcision yourself? What do you mean by that line?