# What is the maximum age for Metzitza?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, brit-milah, minhag

Part of the bris ceremony is metzitza.
I was told that after a certain age (of the boy) it is not done (meaning an adult who gets a bris does not get metzitza).
Is this true?
What is the age?
Source please

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27853/759 Why would age matter?

Comment: @DoubleAA that is my question, but then i thought maybe becouse of hirhur , so maybe the age should be 9

Comment: From that answer it seems some people say it is not necessary, i will try to look up, what age they consider an adult

Comment: @mbloch i mean both (the person (a brother of a mohel  told me no mezitzah is done at all)

Comment: Like Doubleaa intended, age shouldn't matter; but it just gets too weird after a certain point, so it makes sense that it's not done out of human dignity, not because of halacha or an issur. Besides, there's a glass tube used by many mohalim.

Comment: @chacham dignity wouldn't matter either for a Deorayta obligation. (Of course if it's just an archaic health suggestion there's no reason to do it to infants either)

Comment: @DoubleAA +1 you do not say what whould be if it is a dirabonon

Comment: @DoubleAA Actually, it does(gadol kavod haberiot sh'doche lo ta'aseh b'Torah shel lo tasuru(standard pronunciation, i.e. not german)...and doing peri'a without metzitza fulfills the d'oraita obligation, albeit b'diavad; so there's no averah.